# Generar dataframe a partir de una url(fichero son)

Tags: python-3.x

Quiero crear un dataframe a partir de la url que guarda los datos en una columna llamada ListaEESSPrecio donde cada observación es un diccionario, pero no consigo crear un dataframe con todas las observaciones, este es el código. Alguna idea de xq no me genera todas las observaciones?? o alguna forma de hacerlo más corto?? Muchas gracias.

```
df17 = pd.read_json('https://sedeaplicaciones.minetur.gob.es/ServiciosRESTCarburantes/PreciosCarburantes/EstacionesTerrestres/',
                       orient = 'records')
df17_l = df17['ListaEESSPrecio']
df17_1 = df17.ListaEESSPrecio.to_list()
dict={}
for elem in df17_1:
    #print(elem)
    for key, valor in elem.items():
        dict[key] = [valor]

df17_2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict, orient="index").reset_index().T
df17_2.columns = df17_2.iloc[0]
df17_2[1:]
```

Comment: Hola Manuel! Por favor puedes agregar la traza de error completa, o exponer el resultado que tienes y el esperado.

Comment: El código funciona, no da error, pero sólo consigo cargar la última obs cuando debería tener más de 10000.